# Get back your money, or Get your money back

Tags: phrase-usage

> a) **Get** your money **back**.
>   b) **Get back** your money.

Someone says the both sentences are almost similar in the meaning, and exchangable.

But For me, the both meanings are taken like a) and b).

**a)** means the money is yours so you have to ask someone the money back.

**b)** means the money is not yours so you have to return it.

please explain for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To this American English speaker, the meanings are exactly the same.  [*Get back* in this sense means "retrieve"](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/get+back.html), and as you have written the sentences, they're both imperatives, commanding someone else to retrieve their money.  Neither one implies anything about whether the money is really yours or not, or whether you are asking for it or returning it.  Maybe you're confusing it with "**Give** back your money?"

[The first phrasing is the more common one.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get%20your%20money%20back%2Cget%20back%20your%20money)  When you make a sentence like that, you can think of it like

**Get** (*get what?*)
**your money** (*get your money how, or where?*)
**back**.

It is certainly possible to change the word order, as in the title [Gimme Back My Bullets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimme_Back_My_Bullets), but the first order is the more common one.

Comment: Nice answer +1. Would it be wrong if I explain that you could emphasize "your money" in "get your money back" and "back" in "get back your money".

Comment: @stangdon Thank you for answer. Suddenly, the curiosity popped into my mind. :)

Comment: @Rathony - Good question.  I'm not sure; to me changing the word order doesn't really emphasize one or the other, but it's hard for me to say *why* one or the other sounds better!

Comment: @stangdon Thanks for your comment. This question has been bothering me for more than 2 decades. Still I am very curious. :-)